# How to check if multiple conditions are fulfilled?

Tags: pine-script

I would like to trigger an alert/trade when multiple conditions are fulfilled according to the strategy described in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zqUC8dtPphI).

For entering long position, there have to be three conditions fulfilled:

- the price has to be above 200 days EMA (condition 1)
- the relative strength index    has to be above 50
- parabolic SAR has to cross up the current price    (trigger)

For entering short position, parabolic SAR has to cross down the current price.

I just started using pine script, so I would really appreciate if anyone could help me with the example.

Below are is the decomposition into subproblems:

**Checking 200 days EMA:**

```
price = close
slowEMA = ta.ema(close, 200)

// pseudocode
// if price - slowEMA > 0, then condition 1 fulfilled
```

**Checking parabolic SAR:**

```
crossed_up = false
crossed_down = false

start = input(0.02)
increment = input(0.02)
maximum = input(0.2, "Max Value")
out = ta.sar(start, increment, maximum)

// pseudocode
// if out > close and crossed_up is false:
//     trigger_sell = true
//     crossed_up = true
// if out < close and crossed_down is false:
//     trigger_buy = true
//     crossed_down = true

// if out > close and crossed_up is true:
//     trigger_sell = false
//     crossed_up = false
// if out < close and crossed_down is true:
//    trigger_buy = false
//    crossed_down = false
```

**Checking RSI:**

```
buy_condition = false
sell_condition = false

// if RSI is above 50:
//        buy_condition = true
// else:
//        buy_condition = false
//        sell_condition = true
```

**checking all conditions:**

```
// buy
// if price - slowEMA > 0 and trigger_buy and buy_condition:
//        send alert
//        execute buy trigger

// sell
// if price - slowEMA < 0 or crossed_up or sell_condition:
//        send alert
//        execute sell trigger
```

In the parts above, I would like to replace the pseudocode with actual code and put app together.

I don't know how to implement the RSI checking and am not sure if combining multiple conditions the way pseudocode suggests is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use built-in functions as much as possible.

You can use `ta.crossover()` or `ta.crossunder()` functions for your trigger. They will return `true` on the bar that the cross takes place. That would make your life easier.

There is also `ta.rsi()` to calculate the rsi value.

**Condition 1**

```
ema200 = ta.ema(close, 200)
cond1 = (close > ema200) // the price has to be above 200 days EMA
```

**Condition 2**

```
rsi = ta.rsi(close, 14)
cond2 = rsi > 50  the relative strength index has to be above 50
```

**Condition 3**

```
cond3 = ta.crossover(out, close) // parabolic SAR has to cross up the current price
```

Then `and` all those three.

```
long_cond = cond1 and cond2 and cond3
```